# Table to JSON ionic3

Tags: json, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to convert a table in html to JSON, the following code returns a JSON but the content is a table in HTML.

data.ts

```
Get_RSS_Data() {
        this.rssProvider.GetRSS().subscribe(
          data => {
            this.rssDataArray = data;
          }
        );
      }
```

I've been looking and I see that there is a npm "table-to-json" package --> [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/table-to-json)

I have been trying to put the following script in the HTML code of my application in ionic 3, but I can not transform the table.

data.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var table = $('#data.description').tableToJSON();
 </script>
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Please write all of your question in English, then everyone can understand it. Thanks.

Comment: can you sahre exact table that you want to transform to json?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko the code: https://pastebin.com/4U7Vqt6A